# Dynamic Mail Enabled Security Groups are being converted to Dynamic Distribution Lists

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, security-groups

**Problem:** the dynamic mail-enabled security groups (DMESG) I create in EAC are being automatically converted to Dynamic distribution lists (DDL) instead.

**Use Case:**  I am attempting to give membership rights to a DMESG for a shared mailbox.  You can grant membership to a MESG but not a DDL.

The membership criteria for the DMESG is:

> Users with Exchange Mailboxes AND Department = Accounting (as an
> example).

The dynamic membership function does work properly. I created the group using EAC as a Dynamic MESG but when the group gets created, it gets allocated as a Dynamic Distribution List instead, and in that state, I cannot make it a member or give it permissions for the shared mailbox.

While I could manage membership manually, I would really rather take the manual process out of the equation.

Comment: How's everything going now?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, when you create a Dynamic MESG. The Dynamic MESG is included in the DDL. Put another way, DDL contains the Dynamic MESG.

The issue is not related to DMESG is converted to DDL. It's about we can't add distribution lists as delegates of a shared mailbox.  You can only add singer users to it.

Maybe you google it online and  will find some scripts can do it. But it will also be inconvenient...